# KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER event not captured inside onClick

Tags: android, view, click, keyevent, keycode

I have a custom view which extends a ViewGroup. Each of the child view has 3 states

1. Selected state
2. Clicked state
3. Default state

I have implemented onClickListener inside this CustomView. The issue is if any of the child view is in Selected state and then "Center Key" from the keypad is pressed (Keycode corresponds to KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER ) then there is no callback received inside onClick().

If any of the child is clicked or pressed then the onClick() is invoked.

Can anyone let me know how do i map the KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER event to that of onClick() event?